# Jquery easyui datagrid load data from PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-easyui

I want to use jquery easyui, I can load the data into their datagrid using a php file. However I don't want to use one php file for each datagrid and/or action I want to take.
I have been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find a simple answer to this basic question, hopefully someone here can help..

I would like to have a items.php file and in it many different funtions which return either json or any other response and be able to call these funtions from the datagrid.

This is my php file..  I have one function.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "items": get_all_items(); break;
    }
  }

    public function get_all_items(){

    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
    $result = array();

    include 'conn.php';

    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from items");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from items limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);
    }


?>
```

This is my html page where I call the php and the function, but I get nothing back.

```
<table id="dg" title="Articulos" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:1000px;height:330px"
        url="items.php/items" iconCls="icon-search"
        toolbar="#toolbar, #tb" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" data-options="
        url:get_items.php
        >
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I really don't want to have to create a php file for every table and/ or action I need to do upon the data grid.
Basically this same question was asked a few years back, but there was no reply.
https://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=4405.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read POST params in GET request. That's the reason you dont have your function run.

I have no idea what dataGrid is, but it seems like you should change your html to (metion that I have changed url to file and added action param =  'first')

```
<table id="dg" title="Articulos" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:1000px;height:330px"
        url="items.php/items" iconCls="icon-search"
        toolbar="#toolbar, #tb" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" data-options="
        url:get_items.php?action=first
        >
```

Also you'll need to change your php file to accept that param:

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_GET["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "first": get_all_items(); break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but  this did not work. I made the following correction to the url I'm calling above. url="items.php?action=items

Comment: make `var_dump($_GET)` in the beginning of your php code and look are your getting this variable `action` at all or not

Comment: This is the error message I get in chrome developer tools.POST http://example.com/prisma/items.php?action=items 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ VM92:1
send @ jquery-1.6.min.js:16
ajax @ jquery-1.6.min.js:16
loader @ jquery.easyui.min.js:11547
_6e9 @ jquery.easyui.min.js:10790
(anonymous) @ jquery.easyui.min.js:10875
each @ jquery-1.6.min.js:16
each @ jquery-1.6.min.js:16
$.fn.datagrid @ jquery.easyui.min.js:10841
(anonymous) @ jquery.easyui.min.js:74
each @ jquery-1.6.min.js:16

Comment: I just realized that doing var_dump($_GET) would never be displayed, at least not when being called by an ajax call.